# Error setting cookies - Cannot read property '1' of null

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

I have an application deployed on several websites. All UI errors are sent to our server for logging.
We got the following error.

Context: Setting a cookie with plain javascript (no jQuery), using code taken from w3school ([link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)).

Browser: Chrome.

Version: 45.0.2454.101

OS: Linux

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null    
at _parseKeyValuePair (eval at <anonymous> (unknown source), <anonymous>:123:22)
at parseCookie (eval at <anonymous> (unknown source), <anonymous>:73:16)
at HTMLDocument.Object.defineProperty.set [as cookie] (eval at <anonymous> (unknown source), <anonymous>:176:18)
at setCookie (script.min.js:1:3446)
at Array.widgetLoaded (script.min.js:1:11687)
at handleMessage (script.min.js:1:1640)
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (unknown source), <anonymous>:401:13)
```

I can't find any similar exceptions in google. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I think `_parseKeyValuePair` calls a regular expression and access its result without checking it is valid like the following code:

```
function _parseKeyValuePair(str) {
  var result = str.match(/(\w+)=(.+?);/);
  return {key: result[1], value: result[2]);
}
```

But the `result` can be `null` if the regex doesn't match the string. You should check whether the `result` is `null` before access it and use if only if it is not `null`.

For example, the above function can be rewritten like:

```
function _parseKeyValuePair(str) {
  var result = str.match(/(\w+)=(.+?);/);

  if (result !== null) {
    return {key: result[1], value: result[2]);
  }
}
```

Although it is not an exact solution because I don't know about real `_parseKeyValuePair` and `parseCookie`, I'm sure this can help you.

Comment: I think it is helpful :) So, what you are saying is that in order to reprocude it, I need to access non existing cookie entry. is that correct?

Comment: It can be. Can you show me your `_parseKeyValuePair()`? It is helpful to give you a more proper answer.